# Haskell - Compile Error

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

```
data Set a = Set [a]
member xs x = elem x xs
subset xs ys = and (map (member ys) xs)

instance (Eq a) => Eq (Set a) where  
  (Set xs) == (Set ys) = (subset xs ys) && (subset ys xs)

class Ord a => Comparable a where
  cmp :: a -> a -> String
  cmp x y
    | x == y    = "eq"
    | otherwise = "neq"

instance Comparable a => Comparable (Set a) where
  cmp (Set xs) (Set ys)
    | (Set xs) == (Set ys) = "same"
    | otherwise            = "different"
```

I'm getting the following error:

Could not deduce (Ord (Set a))
  arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
from the context (Comparable a)
  bound by the instance declaration for ‘Comparable (Set a)’

I'd like to know what the error is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration

```
class Ord a => Comparable a where
```

states that every member of the class `Comparable` must be a member of class `Ord`. If I were to attempt doing

```
data MyType = ...
instance Comparable MyType where
  cmp x y = "hello"
```

the compiler would complain that an instance `Ord MyType` is missing. IT does not matter that I am not using anything from that `Ord` instance: it is required by the definition of `Comparable`.

To fix that, add an instance

```
instance Ord a => Ord (Set a) where
   compare setA setB = ....
```

After that, you can use your `Comparable` instance, provided you add `Ord a` to the constraints.

```
instance (Ord a , Comparable a) => Comparable (Set a) where
  cmp (Set xs) (Set ys)
    | (Set xs) == (Set ys) = "same"
    | otherwise            = "different"
```

Comment: In this case, you might also simply drop the `Ord` constraint on your `Comparable` class.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson True, but I wasn't sure about what the OP needed, so I left the class as it was posted.

Answer (score 1):

`Comparable` is a subclass of `Ord` so you need to add an instance for `Ord (Set a)` e.g.:

```
instance Ord a => Ord (Set a) where
  compare (Set s1) (Set s2) =
    compare (sort s1) (sort s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You gave a instance of Equality to your set data type but it doesn't have an Ord instance. When you try to  make Set and instance of the Comparable class it requires that Set must be an instance of Ord.